# Start Chrome with allowed extensions list

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I want to start Google Chrome with allowed extensions list. For example I want to leave AdBlock enabled, but all other stuff needs to be disabled.

I'm aware about incognito mode and the `-disable-extensions` flag, but I don't want to see ads.

Any idea?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. But there's an work around. Make your allowed list of extensions works with incognito. Then opening chrome in incognito mode will give you what you want in a sort

Comment: i was enable 2 extensions, Adblock and RSS reader, but icons not appearing at end of address bar as expected

Comment: You can make a new Chrome profile and add selected extensions to it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to start Chrome with only some extensions selectively enabled?](http://superuser.com/questions/496451/how-to-start-chrome-with-only-some-extensions-selectively-enabled)