# How to start Chrome with only some extensions selectively enabled?

Tags: google-chrome, batch, shortcuts, google-chrome-extensions

I'm trying to figure out a way to create a shortcut or batch file, to launch Google Chrome with just the extension "Ad-block" enabled but all other extensions disabled.

I have a shortcut for Chrome with all extensions enabled (for regular use) and a shortcut with `"chrome.exe --disable-extensions"` when I need to run programs that need as much memory as I can give it.

Now I want a shortcut so I can run Chrome with *just* Ad-Block enabled, because browsing the clean Chrome was annoying with all the adds popping up.

Comment: Why not just remove all the other extensions but ad-block in chrome.

Comment: I have a shortcut for Chrome with all extensions allowed (for regular use) and a shortcut with "chrome.exe --disable-extensions" when I need to run programs that need as much memory as I can give it.  Now I want a shorcut so I can run Chrome with JUST "ad-block" on cause the clean Chrome was annoying with all the adds popping up.  Thank you

Comment: While Eduard's new user solution is very easy and elegant, I hope it's not the only option to do this. I'm looking for a way to do this too, and I don't want to create two profiles for that. Anyway, I thought that maybe that way to do this is to disable all extensions but AdBlock by default, and then *somehow* enable all the extensions when launching the regular Chrome shortcut, therefore making the custom Chrome shortcut open with only AdBlock enabled. However, I can't find any way to do this. Maybe the way to do this is by using two `Preferences` files, where each defines enabled extensions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use an extension manager called "[Extensioner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extensioner/pmbfkcgplcmlmoccjbcgmopkbefndhpd)" to manage my extensions.

With it, I created 3 groups of extensions. I can now enable or disable each group at will, with one mouse click.

Comment: Is it possible to enable a specific group automatically through launch options somehow?

Answer (score 3):

You might as well create a create a new user (left upper corner avatar), install addblocker for that user.

Every-time you will change to the newer user  (by clicking left upper corner avatar) a new chrome will open with only addblocker and all the settings made for that account, for me it works like that.

[image]

[image]